# Calling super, super class method with parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I found the below working solutions ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442809/calling-super-class-super-class-method), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629803/can-a-ruby-object-call-super-on-a-grandparent)) which call the grandparent method but without any parameters. Does anyone know how to call the grandparent method with parameters?

```
class GrandParent
  def fun(word)
    puts word
  end
end

class Parent < GrandParent
  def fun(word)
    puts word + 'end'
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def fun(word)
    GrandParent.instance_method(:fun).bind(self).call
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the full code sample in your question, instead of requiring us to read through other people's questions.

Comment: The code you linked to defines a method `Grandparent#fun` without any parameters, so it's invalid to pass parameters to that method.

Comment: However, if `Grandparent#fun` did accept arguments then you can pass them to the `call`: `GrandParent.instance_method(:fun).bind(self).call(parameter_1, parameter_2, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters directly to call like this:

```
class Child < Parent
  def fun(word)
    GrandParent.instance_method(:fun).bind(self).call(param1, param2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`call` accepts parameters

```
GrandParent.instance_method(:fun).bind(self).call word
```

I don't know your use case, but this is a Really Bad Idea™. It creates unnecessary dependencies directly between `Child` and `GrandParent` such that all kinds of normally reasonable refactoring would result in a crash e.g. moving `fun` to only be implemented in `Parent`, changing `Parent` to subclass a different but similar parent, etc.

Comment: This is done for legacy code refactoring. The end goal is to Child < GrandParent. In the meantime, we need the existing implementation for uninterrupted functioning.